# How can my terminal accept input when it's processing a previous command?

Tags: linux, terminal, input

I use Ubuntu Linux on both my personal laptop and my school's computers. On my personal laptop, I'm looking to replicate the behavior of the school's computers where the terminal accepts user input while processing a previous command. For example, when executing `git commit -m "a commit message"`, I'd like to be able to input `git push` while the first command is still processing. I've looked into raw and canonical modes for user input but haven't fully grasped how they work or how to implement them.

Comment: You can do: `command1 & command2`, this will run in //

Comment: @GillesQuénot I'm assuming `//` is referring to parallel.  Just clarifying.

Comment: Yes, sure it is...

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special. The terminal driver automatically buffers input until the application reads it.

Comment: `git commit -m ...` should complete pretty much instantaneously, not sure how you can really type ahead while it's running. For the sake of example, can we replace the first command by `sleep 10`? Does this change the typeahead behavior on any of your computers? Being able to type ahead is the expected behavior. What is the exact behavior on your personal computer where the behavior is not this?

Answer (score 1):

Anything you type while the first command is running will be buffered up as the next command.

The exception would be if the first command reads from standard input, since that wlll read your typeahead. You can avoid that by redirecting the standard input of the first command.

```
command1 < /dev/null
command2
```

I don't think this should happen with your example command. `git commit` will normally prompt for the commit message, but the `-m` option should prevent that. But give it a try, it can't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I think the terminals always accepts extra inputs when executing others, (unless you're running a program that uses the terminal). In your example, it will accept the input, but only execute it when the `git commit` finishes.

PS: I tried it in my PC with `git push` and while it was running used `cd ..` (`git commit` was too fast to test) and it worked.

Comment: that's weird cuz i have tested it in 3 of my friends laptops and it just didn't, while school computers just do exactly as you described

Answer (score -2):

Use a semicolon:

```
git commit -m "foo" ; git push
```

This commits with a message and then pushes it, regardless of success of the commit.

Alternatively, if you only want to push when commit is successful, join the commands with `&&`:

```
git commit -m "foo" && git push
```

Comment: thank you, but i did know to use semicolon and && but it just feels better to type commands from my brain and not have to wait for terminal response